# JS - How to delete a substring that may or may not exist?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to store each of the fields in "text" as its own variable (for example, I want name = Biggie Wiggles, age = 49, etc) and also delete the hobbies section. In the actual data I am using, the "hobbies" field does not always occur, depending on whether it is filled out or not. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance

```
"items": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "text": "Name: Biggie Wiggles Age: 49 Hobbies: Playing golf, catching flies Birthday: 1/1/01",
            "created": "2022-07-04T15:16:41.984Z"
        }
]
```

Comment: By "long string" do you mean JSON?

Comment: Yes, its one of the JSON values returned

Comment: Why not parse the JSON and then `delete` the property.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to explain this but say it returns {id: "123", text: "Field 1: xyz Field 2: abc Field 3: lol"}, and I would be trying to delete Field 2 and its value. Its not comma separate so I cant split it that way, i think

Comment: Whatever that is it isn't valid JSON. Why don't you have your server send you data that is meaningful so you can properly process it?

Comment: The best way to get an answer to this question is to share some _real data_. If it's actual JSON you shouldn't worry about splitting fields, but if it's not it's helpful to see what the data actually looks

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have updated with data!

Comment: regular expressions seem pretty suitable for this problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server isn't giving you great data to work with.  You'll have to parse the values from the "text" property into fields you create yourself on the object.

Here's a super simple example of an implementation you can try. It iterates over your array with the `.map` method, parsing the values of the `"text"` property into new fields in a new object.  Note that this implementation only works if the order of fields in the "text" property doesn't change, but this should be enough to point you in the right direction.

```
var items = [
  {
    "id"      : "123",
    "text"    : "Name: Biggie Wiggles Age: 49 Hobbies: Playing golf, catching flies Birthday: 1/1/01",
    "created" : "2022-07-04T15:16:41.984Z"
  }
].map(item => {
  // we're making an BIG assumption that the order
  // of fields in teh "text" property will always be the same
  var ageIndex   = x.text.indexOf("Age:");
  var hobbyIndex = x.text.indexOf("Hobbies:");

  return {
   id      : x.id,
   created : x.created,
   name    : x.text.substr(0,ageIndex).replace("Name:","").trim(),
   age     : x.text.substring(ageIndex,hobbyIndex).replace("Age:","").trim(),
   hobbies : x.text.substr(hobbyIndex).replace("Hobbies:","").trim()
  }
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic way to do that. Whatever word is given with ":" key will be stored as a key of the object.

```js
const str = "Name: Biggie Wiggles Age: 49 Hobbies: Playing golf, catching flies Birthday: 1/1/01"
let myObj = {}
let lastWord = ""
str.split(" ").forEach(word => {
  if (word.includes(":")) {
    const formattedWord = word.substring(0, word.length - 1); // get rid of :
    myObj[formattedWord] = ""; // assign "" to the key
    lastWord = formattedWord; // store last word to use in else case
  } else {
    myObj[lastWord] = `${myObj[lastWord]} ${word}`.trim(); 
  }
})

console.log(myObj)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let obj ={id: "123", text: "Field 1: xyz Field 2: abc Field 3: lol"}; 
let newObj = obj.text.replace("Field 2: abc", '');  
obj[ 'text'] = newObj 
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this didn't work for me as it returns an error when the field doesnt exist. I think this would work in a situation where the field was always present in the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.